# How to sort numbers in a textview in an UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I have an UITextView in an UITableViewCell which displays a specific rating. How can I sort the UITableView in a way that the textviews are sorted in a from high to low order? This is the code for my textfield in case you need it:

```
let scoreText = UITextView()
                                scoreText.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.5)
                                scoreText.text = (String(userRating)) + " ✨"
                                scoreText.textColor = UIColor.gray
                                scoreText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
                                scoreText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem of `UITextView`. The order of your `UITableView` should be up to the order of the data source. For example,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // In this case YOUR_DATA_LIST needs to be sorted beforehand.
    return YOUR_DATA_LIST.count
}
```

Comment: You said "I have an UITextView in an UITableViewCell" so I assume that you have customised your `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UITextView` in each cell. If you do it this way, the data of each UITextView should be set in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.